# Is there an alternative to do iterative join in spark - scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The use case is to find the n max rows in a given column (these can be n number of columns) and once you have the n keys you join it back to the original dataset to get all the rows you need

val df = Seq(("12", "Tom", "Hanks"),
    ("13", "Meryl", "Streep"),
("12", "Tom", "Hardy"),
("12", "John", "Streep")
).toDF("age", "firstname", "lastname")

Lets say i want to join each column individually with a larger actors dataset which has all the three columns above.

```
val v1 = actors.join(df, Seq("id"), "inner")
val v2 =actors.join(df, Seq("firstname"), "inner")
val v3 =actors.join(df, Seq("lastname"), "inner")
val output = v1.union(v2).union(v3)
```

Is there any way to not to do this iteratively ? Also because the columns to be joined against can be dynamic. for eg sometimes it can only be id, or only be id and firstname.

Comment: read my comments on below 2 answers

Answer (score 2):

You can try different approach, so you can achieve it this way:

```
actors.join(df).where(
actors("id") === df("id") || 
actors("firstname") === df("firstname") || 
actors("lastname") === df("lastname")
)
```

and for n-columns you can try it:

```
  val joinCols = Seq("id", "firstname", "lastname") // or actors.columns
  val condition = joinCols
    .map(s => (actors(s) === df(s)))
    .reduce((a, b) => a || b)
```

you will get below condition:

```
condition.explain(true)
(((a#7 = a#7) || (b#8 = b#8)) || (c#9 = c#9))
```

and finally use it:

```
   actors.join(df).where(condition)
```

Comment: Ah but the column names are dynamic in this case. but this would work perfectly with static columns!

Comment: so then just use `val joinCols = actors.columns`

Comment: aha. i think that would solve my problem. Will confirm and accept answer. Thanks!

Comment: I think this does solve my problem. Running tests to check performance @chlebek Any concerns about performance over doing a broadcast and udf ? Although the broadcast udf approach i dont how i would solve to do filter based on dynamic columns.

Comment: having a non-equi join criteria will cause a cartesian join to run. This doesn't seem optimal. @OP your multiline join would perform much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing a broadcast with the smaller dataset and an udf to check with the bigger dataset would solve the issue. i kept thinking in terms of joins!

Answer (score 0):

@chlebek solution should work perfectly fine, this is one more approach in the case that you want to reproduce your initial logic:

```
val cols = Seq("id", "firstname", "lastname")

val final_df = cols.map{
     df.join(actors, Seq(_), "inner") 
}
.reduce(_ union _)
```

First we generate one *inner join* per column then we *union* them.

Comment: All the joins would be run separately. To minimize data shuffle, `actor` and `df` should be `persisted` or `checkpointed`. Union is a narrow transformation that doesn't incur any shuffles.